# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin z^n$ is uniformly absolutely convergent on compact subset of the unit disk?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin z^n$ is uniformly absolutely convergent on compact subset of the unit disk?

My attempt. If it is $\sum (\sin z)^n$, we may consider $z=iy, y>0$ to see it is not. But $\sin z^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The cosine is bounded in the closed unit disk. It follows that
$$
|\sin(z^n)| \le C \cdot |z^n| = C \cdot |z|^n
$$
for  $|z| < 1$ with some constant $C> 0$. This implies the uniformly absolutely convergence on compact subsets of the (open) unit disk.